# How to compare items stored in a combo box or drop down list and a list in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have created a combo box that stores names of Bluetooth devices and a list that stores names of available paired Bluetooth devices. Now I want to compare an item from combo box to all items stored in the list . Can anyone help me by specifying how can I do it programmatically?

Comment: you can take datasoruce and do it

Comment: let me know what is datasoruce for your combo box ??, some code will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In C#, it would be something like this:

```
if (myAvailablePairedBTDevicesList.Contains(myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    return true;
```

Assuming that both the list and the ComboBox are string types.

Comment: The data source for my combo box is a database which stores information about paired Bluetooth devices. I am only extracting the device name and displaying it in the combo box as a list

Comment: I changed the name of the list to make it more understandable.